# How to solve Oracle http request to rest service TNS: the time allowed for the operation has expired error when I try to call it using utl_http

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql

**I have try to call a REST service using utl_http in PL/SQL , this service worked fine before but now I  get the following errors messages :**

*ORA-29273: HTTP request failure*

*ORA-06512: to "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130*

*ORA-12535: TNS: The test time has elapsed*

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1() IS


    soap_req_msg VARCHAR2(2000);
    http_req  UTL_HTTP.req;
    http_resp UTL_HTTP.resp;
    buffer    varchar2(4000);
BEGIN

soap_req_msg := '{"emailReceiver": "example@mail.com"}'


 http_req := UTL_HTTP.begin_request('<ip_port>/path','POST','HTTP/1.1');
 UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate');
 UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
 utl_http.set_header(http_req, 'SOAPAction', 'processEDIData');
 UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Content-Length', length(soap_req_msg));
 UTL_HTTP.set_header(http_req, 'Host', '<ip_port>');

 UTL_HTTP.write_text(http_req, soap_req_msg);
 http_resp := UTL_HTTP.get_response(http_req);
 begin
   loop
     utl_http.read_line(http_resp, buffer);
     dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
   end loop;
   utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
   exception
   when utl_http.end_of_body then
     utl_http.end_response(http_resp);
 end;

END PROCEDURE1;
```

Comment: what happens if you make that same request from outside the db? sounds like the problem is on the destination side, not the source

Comment: It's work fine outside the db

Comment: How long for a response?

Comment: 229 ms second when I use Postman

Comment: I would check 2 things, if you're on 12c or higher, make sure an ACL isn't blocking you, and 2nd, make sure the server the DB is on can also hit that end point via http https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:9537694000346003353

Comment: I checked acl, it's ok

Comment: I have tried to use a local Oracle  instance running in docker to call my Rest service and it's work fine. I think's this issue is due to network connexion between my Rest server and the dev Oracle server. **Thank you so much** @thatjeffsmith